# How do I get all paragraphs in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, major-mode

I am defining a major mode that works on paragraphs of the following nature:

```
: Identifier
1. some text
2. ...
3. some more text

: New Identifier

: Another Identifier
some text
```

I want to write a `defun` called `get-paragraphs` that will return a list that looks like:

```
(   ("Identifier", ("1. some text", "2. ...", "3. some more text")), 
    ("New Identifier", ()),
    ("Another Identifier", ("some text"))
)
```

How do I go about cutting up the text like this in Emacs Lisp:

Is there a function to iterate through them (and subsequently chop them up to my liking)? Should I use regular expressions? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over the buffer and collect your text (untested):

```
(defun get-paragraphs ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((ret '()))
      (while (search-forward-regexp "^: " nil t)
        (let ((header (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (line-end-position)))
              (body '()))
          (forward-line)
          (while (not (looking-at "^$"))
            (push (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (line-end-position)) body)
            (forward-line))
          (push (cons header (list (reverse body))) ret)))
      (nreverse ret))))
```

Comment: This was almost perfect - there was an extra `=` and I wrapped the lines under the `:` header as another list. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here, take this Lisp code:

```
(defun chopchop ()
  (mapcar 
   (lambda (x)
     (destructuring-bind (head &rest tail)
         (split-string x "\n" t)
       (list head tail)))
   (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties
                  (point-min)
                  (point-max)) "\n?: *" t)))
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Emacs Lisp but I don't think this accurately does what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you at least try it? It does the same as the other answer, only without the errors (it still hangs up when I try it).

Comment: @sdasdadas Actually this behaves the same as the other answer, without the point jumping around.